# Can't Print array with multiple data types

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, struct

I created a struct named `products` that contains multiple data types:

```
struct products{
    int ID;
    string Name;
    double Price;
    int Quantity;
};
```

Then in the main function, I created an array named `details` which utilizes the struct `products`:

```
int main(){
    struct products details[5];
```

Then I gave each array element data.

```
details[0] = {1, "Apple Juice", 12, 240};
details[1] = {2,"Bread", 10, 100};
details[2] = {3, "Chocolate", 5, 500};
details[3] = {4, "Dates", 50, 150};
details[4] = {5, "Eggs", 30, 360};
```

finally, I tried to print the values of the element at index 2:

```
cout<<details[2];
```

it gave me this error:

> "Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'struct products')"

Here is a picture of the whole code

[image]

Comment: you get the same error when you try to print a `products` that is not in an array

Comment: How can the compiler know how to print your struct? You have to define appropriate `operator<<` yourself.

Comment: Try `cout<<details[2].ID` and similar constructs for the other things you want to print

Comment: The array doesn't contain multiple data types - no arrays do. It contains elements of the type `products`. The array is also completely irrelevant; you would see the same error with `products p; std::cout << p;`

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of doing what you need, here's 3 of them:

1. Overload `<<` operator:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const products& pr)
{
    return os << pr.ID << " " << pr.Name << " " << pr.Price << " " << pr.Quantity;
}
```

`std::cout << details[2];` should now work as expected.

---

2. Print the struct members directly:

   ```
   std::cout << details[2].ID << " " << details[2].Name 
       << " " << details[2].Price << " " <<  details[2].Quantity;
   ```

---

3. Add a `to_string()` member function:

```
struct products{
    
//...

    std::string to_string() const
    {
        std::ostringstream os; // #include <sstream>
        os << ID << " " << Name << " " << Price << " " << Quantity;
        return os.str();
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
std::cout << details[2].to_string();
```

Answer (score 0):

i write you like code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct H{
    int n;
    int b;
};

int main() {
    H h[] = {10, 20};
    cout << h[0] << endl; // you can not print it becouse it is array!
    return 0;
}
```

in this code i try to print struct!
but i can not do it!

it like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct H{
    int n;
    int b;
};

int main() {
    H h = {10, 20};
    cout << h << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

just try:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct H{
    int n;
    int b;
};

int main() {
    H h[] = {10, 20};
    cout << h[0].n << endl;
    cout << h[0].b << endl;
    return
```

0;
}